# Translating an integer and a character into several forms in C

Tags: c, integer

In my program I have to:

1. Ask a user for a number and then display that number, then display it as a decimal, an unsigned octal, a hexadecimal, a floating point, a float to two decimal places, then float to three decimal places, a floating point with a signed e and E notation, and a string.
2. Do the same with a character.

I have just been introduced to strings, so I'm not asking about that here. Just show me what in the name of Opera I could be missing?

Since I revised the code, I am able to get results for everything except '%e' and '%o' when I am defining it by a character.

Here's my original code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int usernumber;

int main(void)
{
    int usernumber;
    puts("Please input a number of your choice:");
    scanf("%d", &usernumber);
    printf("%d %i %f %.2f %.3f %e %E", &usernumber);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's my new code (revised on 2014-10-28):

```
int  usernumber ;
char usercharacter;

int main(void) 
{
   int (usernumber);
   int h1 = usernumber;
   int o1 = usernumber;
   int E1 = usernumber;
   int e1 = usernumber;
   char c1 = usernumber;
{
    puts("\n\n------------>Please input a number of your choice:");
    scanf( "%d",&usernumber);
    printf("%d %i %f %.2f %.3f ", usernumber, usernumber, (float) usernumber, (float) usernumber, (float) usernumber);
    printf(" %c"), c1;
    printf(" %X ", h1);
    printf(" %o ", o1);
    printf(" %E ", E1);
    printf(" %e \n ", e1);

}
   char (usercharacter);
   int h2 = usercharacter;
   int o2 = usercharacter;
   int E2 = usercharacter;
   int e2 = usercharacter;
   char c2 = usercharacter;
{
    puts("\n------------>Please input a character of your choice:");
    scanf( " %c",&usercharacter);
    printf("%d %i %f %.2f %.3f", usercharacter, usercharacter, (float) usercharacter, (float) usercharacter, (float) usercharacter);
    printf(" %c"), c2;
    printf(" %X ", h2);
    printf(" %o ", o2);
    printf(" %E ", E2);
    printf(" %e \n ", e2);

}

}
```

(10.30.14)

I have updated my code once again, creating it in a completely new format. Now I am having trouble from the second function carrying the float of the first. The assignment is already late and I will be having points removed for this anyway, however I am still perusing the solution out of curiosity. If anyone has any advice or an explanation for why this may be happening please feel free to comment!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main(void)
{
char user_input[4200];       // The character string used to pull my integers from.
    {
    int input2integer;
    float input2float;
    puts("\n*----> Please input a number of your choice:  <----*");
    system("COLOR 2");
    scanf("%s", user_input);
    input2integer = atoi(user_input);  // Used to translate the character input into an integer.
    input2float = atof(user_input);    //Used to translate the character input into a float.
    printf("Your input was %s\nWhich could be interpreted in the following ways:\n", user_input);
    printf("int = %i\n", input2integer);
    printf("dec = %d\n", input2integer);
    printf("oct = %o\n", input2integer);
    printf("hex = %X\n", input2integer);
    printf("float = %f\n", input2float);
    printf("two digit float = %.2f\n", input2float);
    printf("three digit float = %.3f\n", input2float);
    printf("e float = %e\n", input2float);
    printf("E float = %E\n", input2float);
    printf("char = %c\n", input2integer);
    printf("string = %s\n", user_input);
    }

       char user_input_2[4200];
       {
       int input2integer_2;
       float input2float_2;
       puts("\n*----> Please input a character of your choice: <----*");
       system("COLOR 2");
       scanf("%s", user_input_2);//scans for a string and throws the value into the input array
       input2integer_2 = atoi(user_input_2);//converts the input array into an integer
       input2float_2 = atof(user_input_2);//converts the input array into a float
       printf("The Character selected was was %s\nThe Following are equivalent:\n", user_input_2);
       printf("int = %i\n", user_input_2);
       printf("dec = %d\n", user_input_2);
       printf("oct = %o\n", user_input_2);
       printf("hex = %X\n", user_input_2);
       printf("float = %f\n", input2integer_2);                 // Unfortunately, despite taking extra time on this,
       printf("two digit float = %.2f\n", input2integer_2);       // I failed to prevent this function from carrying the float from the one before.
       printf("three digit float = %.3f\n", input2integer_2);
       printf("e float = %e\n", input2integer_2);
       printf("E float = %E\n", input2integer_2);
       printf("char = %c\n", user_input_2);
       printf("string = %s\n", user_input_2);
       }
return (0);
```

(11.1.14)

This is the final, fully working version of this program!

```
int main(void)
{
char user_input[4200];       // The character string used to pull my integers from.
    {
    int input2integer;
    float input2float;
    puts("\n*----> Please input a number of your choice:  <----*");
    system("COLOR 2");
    scanf("%s", user_input);
    input2integer = atoi(user_input);  // Used to translate the character input into an integer.
    input2float = atof(user_input);    //Used to translate the character input into a float.
    printf("Your input was %s\nWhich could be interpreted in the following ways:\n", user_input);
    printf("int = %i\n", input2integer);
    printf("dec = %d\n", input2integer);
    printf("oct = %o\n", input2integer);
    printf("hex = %X\n", input2integer);
    printf("float = %f\n", input2float);
    printf("two digit float = %.2f\n", input2float);
    printf("three digit float = %.3f\n", input2float);
    printf("e float = %e\n", input2float);
    printf("E float = %E\n", input2float);
    printf("char = %c\n", input2integer);
    printf("string = %s\n", user_input);
    }

       char user_input_2[4200];
       {
       int input2integer_2;
       double input2float_2;

       puts("\n*----> Please input a character of your choice: <----*");
       system("COLOR 2");
       scanf("%s", user_input_2);
       input2integer_2 = atoi(user_input_2);
       input2float_2 = atof(user_input_2);
       input2integer_2 = user_input_2[0]; // *THESE* two lines of code caused me more trouble than everything I have done in this class combined.
       input2float_2 = input2integer_2;   // After a few very sleepless nights, and a massive migraine from staring at screens, I figured them out.
       printf("The Character selected was was %s\nThe Following are equivalent:\n", user_input_2);
       printf("int = %i\n", input2integer_2);
       printf("dec = %d\n", input2integer_2);
       printf("oct = %o\n", input2integer_2);
       printf("hex = %X\n", input2integer_2);
       printf("float = %f\n", input2float_2);
       printf("two digit float = %.2f\n", input2float_2);
       printf("three digit float = %.3f\n", input2float_2);
       printf("e float = %e\n", input2float_2);
       printf("E float = %E\n", input2float_2);
       printf("char = %c\n", user_input_2[0]);
       printf("string = %s\n", user_input_2);
       }
return (0);
}
```

Comment: Try `printf("%d %i %f %.2f %.3f %e %E", usernumber, usernumber, (double) usernumber, (double) usernumber, (double) usernumber, (double) usernumber, (double) usernumber);`

Comment: This worked as well, thank you. However, I am still having trouble getting a character to show up, '%c', in my result. I tried placing '(char)' before the last usernumber, to no avail.

Comment: Also, my first program is somehow running my second. I'm not sure why at this point, however I'm experimenting with it.

Comment: Note that your global variable is unused.  In this program, you don't need `<stdlib.h>` or `<string.h>`.  You seem to have missed the octal and hexadecimal formats (as well as having the problems diagnosed by other people).  You should terminate lines of output with a newline.  I'm mildly curious how you'd plan to print a character as a float.

Comment: Your right, I ran into some serious errors with the method I thought would work. Now I have to tear my code apart.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The headers were there as they are a requirement for my class. In this edit I removed them to relieve all of confusion as to their purpose.

Comment: There are worse sins than unused headers.  Note that the values you cast to `float` are then converted to `double` by the usual conversions that apply to variable-length argument lists used by functions such as `printf()`.  You do need a cast, but I'd probably use `double` rather than `float`.

Comment: Also, your lines `printf(" %c"), c1;` compile, but don't do what you think.  You've misplaced the close parenthesis.  The `%E` and `%e` notations require a `double` argument, not an `int`. Your definition `int (usernumber);` is aconventional; the parentheses are not needed.  You could use just three variables: `int usernumber;`, `double userdouble;` and `char usercharacter;` and then pass these values to the `printf()` statements.  I don't immediately see a reason why `%o` would fail; are you sure it isn't the `%E` and `%e` that are failing?

Comment: And finally (it is half-past bedtime here), it is best not to destroy the original question.  Ideally, you should reinstate your original code, and then add the new code as an amendment.  The trouble is that removing the code makes the original answers irrelevant, which isn't fair to those who helped you.  I'll fix it for you this time; please remember for the future.

Comment: Or maybe not finally…you have global variables that are concealed by the local variables in `main()`.  You may as well remove them since they're unused.  Local variables are better; global variables are sometimes necessary, but not with this program.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  I have progressed further in the class and my studies and recognize all of the errors you pointed out in the second version of my code. I am trying to fix it, to see if it wont' work for me, however it would no longer have a string, which is what my third version has. This assignment is difficult, and I keep hitting walls.

Answer (score 7):

Format specifiers only make sense if you provide an argument to printf for each specifier.

If you have 8 format specifiers in the printf string, you need 8 occurences of usernumber in the argument list.

```
printf("%d",    usernumber);
printf("%d %i", usernumber, usernumber);
...
```

Also, printf doesn't use the address of its arguments like scanf. It doesn't have to write to them. So remove the `&` as I showed above for printf.

Keep in mind, that you are hinting to printf what sort of variable you are passing. Because printf() uses variable argument lists (untyped lists), if you pass it something incompatible with the format specifier hints (int for a %f or a variable of the wrong size), the output may be wrong. Consider casting the argument, or moving to a temporary variable. (Regarding casting, keep in mind it only produces a converted value, it doesn't change the original variable)

Comment: ALRIGHT ok, that worked out pretty damn well I got one problem though @codenheim is that my floats won't even go, they just show zero values, any thoughts?

Comment: See my update. Format specifiers need to be compatible with the argument type. If not, you need to convert.

Comment: Ah, I see now! Ok, temporary variables... to the Google machine.

Comment: Or just casts. (float)usernumber

Comment: Your last suggestion, casts, was brilliant. I'd never heard of it until now, and it did wonders to my code and definitely expanded my knowledge. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: would you mind looking at the latest version of my code? I am having a problem with my floats carrying to the second function.

Comment: The second function in my code, intended to translate a Character into several forms, is not interpreting the inputted character as a float at all, rather it is bringing down the floats of the function before it. For example, if the first function, asking for a number, is *11* - than the second function asking for a character will have *11* as its float values as well, regardless of what is entered.

Comment: One issue: `printf("char = %c\n", user_input_2);` is wrong, you can't  format a char array / pointer to a %c like that. You print/format the first character in the array with %c if you do `user_input_2[0]` but not the whole array.

Comment: These are wrong too: `printf("int = %i\n", user_input_2);` and the lines after it where you are print out user_input_2 as different numberic formats are not correct. You probably meant `input2integer_2` and `input2float_2` (remember you can't pass a char array to a numeric formatter, thats why you are converting it first)

Comment: If you want to chat, we can chat offline instead of in the thread, but I have to go for now. (You can call my attention to question by sending me email, my email is in my profile)

Comment: Your saying that instead of 'printf("char = %c\n", user_input_2);' i should define 'user_input_2[0] = char a_name_here'?

Comment: No, Im not saying that. `user_input_2[0]` is already there, that means the first character in the array/string.

Answer (score 7):

If your compiler isn't telling you where you're going wrong with your third attempt, you need to get yourself a better compiler.  GCC will tell you about the multitude of errors with minimal provocation.  This is a simple fixup; you just need to make sure you get the right type for each format, as before.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char user_input[4200];
    int input2integer;
    float input2float;
    puts("\n*----> Please input a number of your choice:  <----*");
    //system("COLOR 2");
    scanf("%s", user_input);
    input2integer = atoi(user_input);
    input2float = atof(user_input);
    printf("Your input was %s\nWhich could be interpreted in the following ways:\n", user_input);
    printf("int = %i\n", input2integer);
    printf("dec = %d\n", input2integer);
    printf("oct = %o\n", input2integer);
    printf("hex = %X\n", input2integer);
    printf("float = %f\n", input2float);
    printf("two digit float = %.2f\n", input2float);
    printf("three digit float = %.3f\n", input2float);
    printf("e float = %e\n", input2float);
    printf("E float = %E\n", input2float);
    printf("char = %c\n", input2integer);
    printf("string = %s\n", user_input);

    char user_input_2[4200];
    int input2integer_2;
    float input2float_2;
    puts("\n*----> Please input a character of your choice: <----*");
    //system("COLOR 2");
    scanf("%s", user_input_2);
    input2integer_2 = atoi(user_input_2);
    input2float_2 = atof(user_input_2);
    printf("The Character selected was was %s\nThe Following are equivalent:\n", user_input_2);
    printf("int = %i\n", input2integer_2);
    printf("dec = %d\n", input2integer_2);
    printf("oct = %o\n", input2integer_2);
    printf("hex = %X\n", input2integer_2);
    printf("float = %f\n", input2float_2);
    printf("two digit float = %.2f\n", input2float_2);
    printf("three digit float = %.3f\n", input2float_2);
    printf("e float = %e\n", input2float_2);
    printf("E float = %E\n", input2float_2);
    printf("char = %c\n", user_input_2[0]);
    printf("string = %s\n", user_input_2);

    return(0);
}
```

Compilation using GCC (source file `xyz.c`):

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition -Werror xyz.c -o xyz
```

Sample run (user supplied data is 48 and 0):

```
*----> Please input a number of your choice:  <----*
48
Your input was 48
Which could be interpreted in the following ways:
int = 48
dec = 48
oct = 60
hex = 30
float = 48.000000
two digit float = 48.00
three digit float = 48.000
e float = 4.800000e+01
E float = 4.800000E+01
char = 0
string = 48

*----> Please input a character of your choice: <----*
0
The Character selected was was 0
The Following are equivalent:
int = 0
dec = 0
oct = 0
hex = 0
float = 0.000000
two digit float = 0.00
three digit float = 0.000
e float = 0.000000e+00
E float = 0.000000E+00
char = 0
string = 0
```

---

This is a unified diff between the formatted version of your version 3 code and the code I posted.  The lines marked with `-` are old lines that were deleted; the lines marked `+` are new lines that were inserted.

```
--- xyz-bust.c  2014-10-30 21:39:38.000000000 -0700
+++ xyz-fixed.c 2014-10-30 21:12:29.000000000 -0700
@@ -33,16 +33,16 @@
     input2integer_2 = atoi(user_input_2);
     input2float_2 = atof(user_input_2);
     printf("The Character selected was was %s\nThe Following are equivalent:\n", user_input_2);
-    printf("int = %i\n", user_input_2);
-    printf("dec = %d\n", user_input_2);
-    printf("oct = %o\n", user_input_2);
-    printf("hex = %X\n", user_input_2);
-    printf("float = %f\n", input2integer_2);
-    printf("two digit float = %.2f\n", input2integer_2);
-    printf("three digit float = %.3f\n", input2integer_2);
-    printf("e float = %e\n", input2integer_2);
-    printf("E float = %E\n", input2integer_2);
-    printf("char = %c\n", user_input_2);
+    printf("int = %i\n", input2integer_2);
+    printf("dec = %d\n", input2integer_2);
+    printf("oct = %o\n", input2integer_2);
+    printf("hex = %X\n", input2integer_2);
+    printf("float = %f\n", input2float_2);
+    printf("two digit float = %.2f\n", input2float_2);
+    printf("three digit float = %.3f\n", input2float_2);
+    printf("e float = %e\n", input2float_2);
+    printf("E float = %E\n", input2float_2);
+    printf("char = %c\n", user_input_2[0]);
     printf("string = %s\n", user_input_2);
 
     return(0);
```

You say:

> In this example you didn't get the float effect I was; however I do not see why.

I'm not sure what float effect you are referring to.  However, you an observe that I changed the argument to `printf()` for each and every one of the floating point formats.

> The compiler I'm using is Codeblocks, as it is what my class is using.

[Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) is an IDE.  It can be configured to use different compilers.  You've not identified which compiler you're using with Code::Blocks.  However, if you can't find a way to make your compiler complain about the errors in your code, get yourself a better compiler (and use it with Code::Blocks).  One of the compilers it can use is GCC; if what you're currently using isn't GCC and you can't persuade it to reject your code as posted in Update 3, get GCC installed and configured — unless there's some stupid rule about "you must use some other compiler".  But most of the compilers it supports can be made to be fussy:

> [Multiple compiler support](http://www.codeblocks.org/features):
>
> - GCC (MingW / GNU GCC)
> - MSVC++
> - clang
> - Digital Mars
> - Borland C++ 5.5
> - Open Watcom

MSVC++ requires `/W3` or thereabouts to enable stringent warnings, IIRC.  There are probably more subtle ways to set the warnings too; that tends to get rather noisy because it thinks standard C functions are not safe.  Both GCC and `clang` will take the options I showed.  I'd expect Digital Mars to be comparable to, but different from, GCC and `clang`.  I don't know the Borland or Open Watcom compilers, but they can probably have their arms twisted into compiling with stringent warnings enabled.

Comment: I don't understand. In this example you didn't get the float effect I was, however I do not see why. The compiler I'm using is Codeblocks, as it is what my class is using.

Comment: Code::Blocks is an IDE, not a compiler.  It uses a compiler; you don't say which compiler, though.  See my update.

Comment: I am using GCC (MingW as my compiler). I apologize for the confusion on my part.

Comment: You're not the first to be confused, and are unlikely to be the last either. One of the disadvantages of using an IDE is that it blurs the difference between the different tools — at least, to people who learned the tools separately (like me), that's a disadvantage. You should, therefore, be able to set Code::Blocks so that it always compiles your code with options `-O3 -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror` (and maybe the other options I used too). It will be a setting for the build process. Using those flags will ensure that the code you write is fairly clean — it simply won't compile really bad code.

Comment: After looking up _unified diff_ I am beginning to understand what your saying. You are going over my head at this point. The compiler is giving me the warning that '%e %f%E' (etc) expects the argument _int_ but argument 2 has type _char *_.

Comment: so I add that piece of code to my program? Or is it an option setting?

Comment: The compiler options are an option setting somewhere in Code::Blocks.  Since I've not got it installed anywhere, I can't be more precise than that.

Comment: I've changed 'input2integer_2' to 'input2float_2' (a fairly obvious error), and now I receive only zero values for my floats. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: The compiler should not be reporting that `%e` expects `int`; it should be expecting `double` (and `float` values are automatically promoted to `double` in the argument list of `printf()` et al).

Comment: What character did you enter as the data?  I used 48 and 0; maybe you should use 49 and 1, or 57 and 9.  The significance of these pairs is that the ASCII code for digit 0 is 48, for digit 1 is 49, for digit 9 is 57.  If you enter something like 'A', you will get zeros because both `atoi()` and `atof()` return 0 when the string can't be converted.

Comment: Right! '%e' is taken care of, however now I get 0 values for everything save the character and string values...

Comment: That makes the second half pretty much useless. Perhaps I missed something obvious again?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you're expected to do, but I think you should consider using: `input2integer_2 = user_input_2[0]; input2float_2 = input2integer_2;` and then the printing code should work OK as is (or as fixed).

Comment: should we move this to chat? And that's the essence of my problem, I need to insert a character such as 'A' 'B' etc.

Comment: I's love to move it to chat, but the silly system won't let us because you don't have enough reputation.  It is pointless saying "move to chat" when it then won't let us.  Maybe I should file another bug on Meta about this (though I don't think it's been responded to constructively before).  If you type 'A' and use the code I showed (`input2integer_2 = user_input_2[0]; input2float_2 = input2integer_2;`), then there will be 65 in the integer, and 65.00 in the float.

Comment: That seems like a dumb policy, considering it will be n00bs who will need the most guidance... that's why I cant eve post about my other programs too. Oh well. Is there a particular area where I should place that? I'm still receiving '0's when I run it.

Comment: (a) See [SO should not invite you to move a discussion to chat when one of the participants doesn't have enough reputation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275771/).